# Programmatically disabling shutdown hook in log4j 2

Tags: log4j2, shutdown-hook

It's possible to disable shutdown hooks in log4j2 via configuration:

```
<Configuration shutdownHook="disable">
```

Is it possible to do so programmatically?

Comment: The link tells me how to disable shutdown hooks via configuration, and shutdown log4j2 manually in code. It doesn't tell me how to disable shutdown hooks in code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know, it's probably outdated but I felt on your question and I was in the same situation. So for people interested, I use this piece of code to stop the shutdown hook programmaticaly :

```
final LoggerContextFactory factory = LogManager.getFactory();

if (factory instanceof Log4jContextFactory) {
    LOG.info("register shutdown hook");
    Log4jContextFactory contextFactory = (Log4jContextFactory) factory;

    ((DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry) contextFactory.getShutdownCallbackRegistry()).stop();
}
```

and in my own shutdown hook

```
LogManager.shutdown();
```

log4j2: 2.8.2 (but should be available since 2.6)